# Select with oracle in php doesnt echo value

Tags: php, oracle, post, get, oracle-call-interface

When i execute this dont happen anything

```
if(empty($_POST) === false) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :use ';
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    echo $username;
```

but if i put $a instead  $username in oci_bind_by_name everything is ok

```
    $a='andrei';
     echo $a;
     oci_bind_by_name($stid, 'use', $username);
     oci_execute($stid);
     while (oci_fetch($stid)) {
     echo oci_result($stid, 'ID') ; }
   oci_free_statement($stid);
   oci_close($conn);
```

what i do wrong ?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Yes array ( 'username' => 'root', 'password' => '1234', ) that is what i see,now what i do ?

Comment: Try to check if-condition other way. `if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))`

Comment: Same result another variable can see value from $username but oci_bind_my_name() not.Do you have another solution  ?

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: No,just  echo oci_result($stid, 'ID') ; dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve with

```
$v = var_export($username, true);
$b = str_replace("'", "", $v);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, 'use', $b);
```